# Sum column no in excel with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Excel as Below

```
   A        B     C    D    E
1 Result  sub1  sub2 sub3 Total
2 Ram     sub3  sub2 sub3 2
3 hari    sub1  sub3 sub2 1
```

here in above example Total = count of correct result ie in B for ram sub3 != sub1 so it is not counted for  Total but C and D are right.
I am trying it but i can not get result What is formula for total in  Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx):

Use the following formula in E2, then simply fill down. Obviously adjust the ranges if you have more data than your example:

```
{=SUM(IF($B2:$D2=$B$1:$D$1,1,0))}
```

Note this is an array formula. To enter it, enter the formula `=SUM(IF($B2:$D2=$B$1:$D$1,1,0))`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This works by doing exactly as you explain. It checks each cell in the range if it equals the value in row 1, then either adds a 1 or a 0 depending on if it matches.

Comment: =SUM(IF($C2:$E2=$C$1:$E$1,1,0)) or =SUM(IF($B2:$D2=$B$1:$D$1,1,0)) @lc.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. B to D. I'd copied the row numbers by accident to test.